# Why in `numpy.convolve` If v is longer than a, the arrays are swapped before computation?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

The NumPy `convolve` [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) and [codebase](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L850) mentions that

`if v is longer than a, the arrays are swapped before computation`

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Not sure, but I think it has to do with the fact that there is also a `mode` called 'same', which returns an array with the size of the signal. That could give an invalid result, _e.g._ when convolving a 2-point signal with a 256-point filter.

Comment: It makes no difference at all, and there's no reason to mention it... but I bet there *was* a reason to mention in in a previous version of the docs that didn't have careful language to make clear that the sizes M and N are interchangeable.